# How do I get a count on inserted rows for INSERT query with nested SELECT? No luck with affected_rows, result_id, num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The INSERT statement with SELECT in VALUES:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO weld_reference(weld_id,report_id) VALUES ((SELECT w.id FROM welds w WHERE w.weld_number=?),?)")
```

The below code loops through an array of user submited strings ($welds) and tries insert its ID into table `weld_reference` if it exists in table `welds`.

```
    $stmt->bind_param("si",$weld_number,$_POST['report_id']);
    foreach($welds as $weld_number){
        if($stmt->execute() and $stmt->num_rows){
            ++$insert_count;
        }
    }
```

I don't want to do another query to see if the row exists, I was hoping that I could get the number of rows or success of the INSERT after each $stmt->execute().

However, `$stmt->affected_rows`, and `$stmt->insert_id` always returns 1 and
`$stmt->num_rows` always returns `0` whether a row was inserted or not.

How can I get a read on this and see if a row has been inserted to send an accurate feedback message to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you check the value of `$stmt->insert_id`? Because it should return you "Get the ID generated from the previous INSERT operation". If ou only ($evaluate) it it will return true (as 1)

The way i do it is i store the id's in an array so i can have a nice list of what has been inserted.

```
$stmt->bind_param("si",$weld_number,$_POST['report_id']);
    foreach($welds as $weld_number){
        if($stmt->execute()){
          $insertedId[]=$stmt->insert_id;
        }
    } 
echo count($insertedId);
```

Or since an id would logicaly never be empty you could do

```
$stmt->bind_param("si",$weld_number,$_POST['report_id']);
    foreach($welds as $weld_number){
        if($stmt->execute() && !empty($stmt->insert_id)){
            $insert_count++;
           // ++$insert_count; //unaware of this syntax -.-
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked, I also had to change my query to `INSERT INTO nde_report_weld_reference(weld_ref_id,nde_report_ref_id,pass_bool) 
         SELECT w.id,?,? FROM welds w WHERE w.weld_number=?`. Appearantly this was inserting rows all the time with NULL values. I didn't realize that the app was ignoring those rows. Also, I think ++$ is perfectly valid [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm jut not used to see this syntax. Just like `and` vs `&&`. Glad it worked, hope you've learned something :D